# Why can't I access a UILabel within a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Scenario: 
Attempting to make a basic n x n collection flow layout.
[image]

I merely placed a one-char UILabel with a tag #1 in the middle of a stock cell.

I intended to grab this UILabel and populate it with a single weekday initial.

I do this by grabbing the UILabel from the cell and set its value:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger item = indexPath.item;

    BOOL isTitleRow = (item <= 6);

    if (isTitleRow) {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kWeekDayHeaderCell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath];

        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        label.text = [self dayHeaderStringFor:item];

        return cell;
    } else {
        InspectionCalendarCollectionViewCell *cell = (InspectionCalendarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kMonthDayCell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

But I'm not getting anything, so I start checking to find that the UILabel is nil (even though by default it should have the letter 'W'):

```
(lldb) po label
nil
(lldb) po cell
<UICollectionViewCell: 0x7fdc93f4b180; frame = (0 0; 32 32); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdc93f4a050>>

(lldb) po cell.contentView
<UIView: 0x7fdc93f4b730; frame = (0 0; 0 0); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdc93f4c630>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdc93f49fd0>>

(lldb) po cell.contentView.subviews
<__NSArrayI 0x7fdc93f00bc0>(

)
```

Why is the cell's contentView layout is zeroes? 
Why no subviews listed within cell?   --- IB has them. 
What am I missing here?